# How to parse a String which is a multidimensional array representaion

Tags: android

I'm now working on Java on Android platform and facing problem extracting the strings out of a string as followings

```
result.toString();
```

The `toString` is expected to return the results as following:

```
[ search[name = Tulsa, code = 1234], search[name = Victo, code = 1232] ]
```

Then, may I know what is the best and the efficient way to store the results returned into arrays like followings:

```
array[0][0] = "Tulsa";
array[0][1] = 1234;
array[1][0] = "Victo";
array[1][1] = 1232;
```

or is there any more efficient, better way available for storing?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "efficient" ?

Comment: what type is the result of? And are there no better accessors for the values?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `result.toString().split(",")` which will return you a String array. But it seems that not your case.

P.S. Could you specify what the "code" in toString method is?

P.S. I think the most efficient way is to use Map. In that case you could just use

```
map.put("Tulsa",1234)

map.put("Victo",1234)
```

etc